# Finding Complex expression

Tags: complex

How do you find a real part of a complex expression?

Here is an example of what I am looking for

```
complexExpand[Sqrt[x + I*b]]
```

gives me

```
(b^2 + x^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 Arg[I b + x]] + I (b^2 + x^2)^(1/4) Sin[1/2  Arg[I b + x]],
```

while there exists expression which does not contain cos or arg (just x and b).

Comment: "Dummy machine didn't accept my question, so I have to type. I am curious if it will be accepted."  What? Also, look up `Re` in the *Mathematica* documentation.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. It only work with numbers, not with expressions.

Comment: Without a lot more information/specifics in the post, looking up `Re` in the documentation is the only answer we can give you. If you edit your post with more information about your specific case, complete with a simple (but not too simple that it doesn't show the problem) example of your use-case, then perhaps we can be more specific. Otherwise, this will likely soon be closed as "unclear what you're asking". But also try `ComplexExpand` along with `Re`, perhaps.

Comment: Please *edit your original post* with this information, properly formatted in code blocks. Click the grey question mark on the right side of the editing toolbar for formatting help.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Re[Sqrt[x + I*b]]]` works, once you realize that up to branch-cuts, `ArcTan[x,b] == Arg[I b + x]`.

Comment: I do not need sin, cos or ArcTan. I just need an expression containing nothing but roots. How to get it?

Comment: I guess, your computer don't know about is X or b `Real` or not. So, you should look for `Assumtions` in context of `ComplexExpand`.

Comment: @Rom38 `ComplexExpand` does not take an `Assumptions` option. It assumes all variables are real-valued unless they appear in the (optional) second argument.

Comment: The result I am looking for is Re[Sqrt[x + I*y]] = 1/2 Sqrt[2 (SQrt[x^2+y^2]+x)]. How can I get it?